# Is onDestroy called in an application when the phone runs out of battery?

Tags: android, shutdown, ondestroy, application-shutdown, system-shutdown

Would the onDestroy method be called when the phone runs out of battery? I would imagine that it doesn't. Unfortunately, I don't have a phone to test this on right now, otherwise I would just check for myself.

Comment: `I would imagine that it doesn't. ` i imagine that when the phone has 0.0% battery left, it actually has 0.5% left, that it uses to shut down everything before really dying, but that is just a guess

Comment: hmm that would be nice. I suppose it would make sense for it to do that. If the phone actually shuts down and destroys all apps then it would mean onDestroy would be called

Comment: no it will not call onDestroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reality there is no telling what will happen. There's even doubt about if `onDestroy()` will be called under normal circumstances.

One of the few situations where `onDestroy()` in an `Activity` *SHOULD* be called is when using the `BACK` button or if an event in the `Activity` explicitly results in calling `finish()`. In result, and in theory, the `Activity` will be stopped (`onStop()` is called) then destroyed (`onDestroy()` is called).

The ambiguity WRT the clean *shutdown* of app components comes when processes are actually 'killed' - this is why Task Killers are so evil as they basically forcibly rip the process out of memory regardless of running state and usually prevent any cleanup operations to occur.

In an absolute emergency (such as when the battery is at absolute minimum), the system will do its level best to shut down any running processes as cleanly as possible but there's no guarantee it will do this successfully.

In particular, if you have any 'mission critical' data or state which needs to be saved then do it when an `Activity` is paused (i.e., in `onPause()` or at the very least when it is stopped (in `onStop()`).

I personally rarely make use of `onDestroy()` for the reasons I've outlined above - in general I work on the creation -> start -> resume -> pause -> stop - restart life-cycle methods.

Finally, you have to remember your app may have a number of different components (Activities, Services and either an explicit or implicit Application) - in the case of a low battery shutdown, each of these components may be handled differently. All in all, however, if the process is 'ripped' ot of memory and forcibly stopped, there's no guarantee of what you'll find once you've re-charged the battery and restarted your app unless you plan for saving data and / or state.

Answer (score 1):

I can't check right now, but since a device goes through the whole shutdown routine before actually passing out, you could test it in the simulator by powering it off (F7 to emulate power button)

Hope it helps!

Comment: using the emulated powerbutton, will not simulate a dying battery. it will just shut down the device and before it will close all the services.

Comment: My point here was that when the device notice that it has only ~1% left, he will shutdown properly by itself, calling all the necessary stuff. Of course, if the battery is hot removed or really "dies", your app won't be aware of that (no fallback, it just stops)

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not call onDestroy() method.
As this is called only when activity is destroyed or exited, but in your case whole application gets removed from the memory.
Better option is to keep track of battery, and when it reaches to 0.5% or 0.6% run your commands which you want to run at onDestroy.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite complicated to say but in my opinion, When the device unexpectedly shuts down, the OS calls onDestroy() on everything